# Fetch PHP quiz result from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I have a multiple answer quiz created in PHP that posts the answers to a table in MySQL. There is no correct answer. There are 9 questions. The questions are radio buttons with names from a to i and the multiple answers are given the values from 1 to 4. This is the form:

**Avoiding paying the fare on public transport.**

    1. Never justified.
    2. Rarely justified.
    3. Sometimes justified.
    4. Always justified.

How do I fetch the result in these two forms:

1. how many values of 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 out of all 9 questions have been selected.
2. total sum of all the values selected.

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tests`.`integrity` 
 ( `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
   `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
   `q1` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
   `q2` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
   `q3` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
   `q4` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
   `q5` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
   `q6` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
   `q7` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
   `q8` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
   `q9` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = MyISAM;

   $sql = "INSERT INTO integrity (name, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9)   
           VALUES ('$value1', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5',   
           '$value6', '$value7', '$value8', '$value9', '$value10')";
```

Example of the result could be: You scored 9 
(in case the value selected to all the questions was 1 Never justified)

Up to 15: 
You are a very honest person who really wants to do the right thing.
15 up to 20
You are above average in integrity, but you do not mind bending the rules occasionally.
20 up to 25
You are relaxed about braking the rules when it suits you, but you are not fundamentally dishonest.
25 plus You do not believe in living by the rules and find it easy to break them when it suits you.

Comment: ...and do you have a (specific) question?

Comment: How to fetch the result in two forms: 1. how many values of 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 out of all 9 questions have been selected. 2. total sum of all the values selected.

Comment: Please provide the table definition (preferably as valid `CREATE TABLE ...` statements), some example data (preferably as valid `INSERT INTO ...` statements) and example results (based on the example data).

Comment: I think that there's a correct answer.

Comment: There is no correct answer.

Comment: Before you go any further, read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because you've got some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) here.

Comment: Also worth noting that you've violated the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Seeing columns like `q1`, `q2`, etc. is a sign you're doing something wrong. You should have multiple questions in a separate table related to their `integrity` record via an `id` reference. Additionally, please **do not** use the MyISAM engine. It's not transactional, and it can suffer catastrophic data loss if your server crashes because it lacks a journal.

Comment: q1, q2, etc. I have used here instead of 'question1', 'question2', etc.

Comment: are you actually using  the `quiz-engine` which you added as a tag?

Comment: The types of q1,q2,.. should be TINYINT and not VARCHAR as they will only store the numbers 1,2,3 or 4.

Comment: I changed the types to TINYINT, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yipes. All kinds of data integrity problems here. You have numeric values in `varchar(255)` columns. You've ruled out quizzes with ten or more questions. And you're using MyISAM which doesn't offer transactional integrity. And you better hope one of your users doesn't have the name "johnny droptables" (look it up).

But never mind all that stuff. We developers grumble about it because of, well, our integrity. Most of us have coped with too many hacked websites to let it pass. Let's answer your question.

You can retrieve each person's total score this way. This shows them in ascending order.

```
       SELECT name, q1+q2+q3+q4+q5+q6+q7+q8+q9 score
         FROM integrity
        ORDER BY q1+q2+q3+q4+q5+q6+q7+q8+q9 ASC, name
```

You can create a histogram-like table like this. This shows how many people received each distinct score.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) number_of_people, scores.score
  FROM (
         SELECT name, q1+q2+q3+q4+q5+q6+q7+q8+q9 score
           FROM integrity
          ORDER BY q1+q2+q3+q4+q5+q6+q7+q8+q9
       ) scores
 GROUP BY scores.score
 ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC, scores.score
```

Note. This will silently ignore values that start with letters.

I suggest you get this working and then ask again about classifying each score.